# IIS responds with Content Length 0 if Accept Encoding header is NOT passed

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, iis, aws-lambda

**Setup**: Lambda running on Java 8/AWS Linux 1, making HTTPS calls to IIS 10 running on Windows 2019 datacenter, application server tomcat.

When a user drops a config file into an S3 bucket, I am using a lambda function to do HTTP `POST /files` to my website to inform about the file upload with its contents.

The POST responds back to lambda with a large body usually of 500KB in size. I am having trouble with the response headers where I always see `Content-Length: 0`.

If I make the request via postman, I get the response, and the Content-Length: 0. After much poking around, I found that IIS 10(my web server) is not providing a `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`, and so my lambda is thinking there is no response and so closing the connection.

Upon comparing the headers between Postman and Lambda i found that the "Accept Encoding: gzip" is missing in lambda calls. So, i removed the header in Postman as well, and i saw the behaviour of 0 content length.

In my IIS, i have enabled static and dynamic compression. So, why is IIS not automatically defaulting to non compressed/identity mode? What am i missing here in the configuration?

Comment: IIS is not at fault here. It turns out there is bug with the application (Lucee) running on tomcat. If `Content-Encoding` is not passed, the application is unable to understand what encoding should it use, and worse its failing silently. The bug has been fixed now and the whole flow is working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

> i have enabled static and dynamic compression

It is not static and dynamic compression, what you should check is Static Content.

Internet Information Services > WWW Services > Common HTTP Features > Static Content.

[image]

Comment: Its installed. yet no change.

Comment: It is difficult to reproduce your problem, I suggest you open a case via: https://support.microsoft.com.

Comment: I didn't have lambda involved, but the internet brought me here when IIS was returning 0 content length for existing text/html files with valid lengths and this solved it for me. thanks!